# Is there a way to remove flexmock from an object?

Tags: python, flexmock

You've mocked this module/object:

```
flexmock(foo)
```

Is there any way to reverse this process, so that when you call into foo, you can be sure that you're not hitting a mocked method?

This would enable testing different components in isolation. If I where to name the method, I'd make it look like

```
foo.unmock()
```

But I don't think that method actually exists.

Comment: This was mostly a problem with our test framework `mamba` not cleaning up after itself.